# Show left axis label width fixed or mulitline in Charts library?

Tags: ios, charts, swift3

I am using charts(https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library for design charts in my application.
I am facing issue with display label width, I am trying to set fixed width label so that I can display the chart in max space. but now title text taking too much space of the screen. 
how can we avoid this problem?

here is the screenshot for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try set multiline mode for label:

```
label.numberOfLines = 2
label.text = "Regional Safety\nWalks"
```

Comment: it's not that simple, I have found the same query posted in their issue list(charts). and they have not given this feature for a bar chart.